# Close the terminal after finishing execution

Tags: c, linux, sh

How do I close the Linux terminal window after executing my C program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int si,p,t,r;
   printf("Enter p t r");
   scanf("%d %d %d",&p, &t, &r);
   si = (p * t * r) / 100;
   printf("%d",si);
     // after finishing task i want to close the terminal 
 }
```

After compiling my program in Ubuntu terminal, I run my program:

```
./a.out
```

After execution of my program, terminal should close automatically.
How to do that?

Comment: Learn about `batch`, `cron`, `at` .. You probably need some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell your shell to exec the program instead of running it, so that it replaces the shell.

```
exec ./a.out
```

Comment: can i close the terminal by writing some line inside my program ?

Comment: You could try some backflips and some stupid code tricks, but there would inevitably come a day when things would go horribly, horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For bash terminal

```
./a.out && exit
```

Comment: But if the exit code of the command is not 0, something is wrong, and you probably want the terminal to stay open in that case...

Answer (score -1):

try writing **system("exit")** as the last line in the code. I have tried **system("cls")** on mingw and it worked

Comment: This answer shows a failure to understand the fundamental nature of `system()`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I dont have much idea regarding this but can we not use system calls in such code. Can you plz tell where and when system calls should be used

Comment: `system()` opens a new shell. It should only be used in "fire-and-forget" situations where an external command needs to be run that would have no direct effect on the program.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams system("cls") clears the same terminal, so is it effecting the program? He wants to close the same terminal, will system("exit") wont do that?

Comment: It is not affecting the program, only the terminal. `system("exit")` will only exit the shell that `system()` runs.

Comment: I have a doubt, we learned that system(" command ") will create a new shell and execute the command. But how come sysytem ("clear") clean the current shell(where program is running in current terminal)

Comment: @Roshanshetty: Because the terminal has nothing directly to do with the program; the program simply has its std* connected to it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams how to pass the error messages to special file /Dev/nul in system() function, I have tried this system("Firefox -h > /Dev/null") but its not working, after running that in c its displaying the error messages